# DNS issues after NS changes

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

We were experimenting with moving to a new Name Server Provider yesterday, so we switched our NS records a few times (about 3-4 times) during the course of the day. We have it set now on the original settings, but the website does not load anymore. It works on some computers, not others.

If we run

> dig ourdomain.com

it hangs, but with

> dig ourdomain.com +trace

it shows the correct information. Also, when logging in to one of our remote servers (in Germany) it works fine.

Could this be a problem with the DNS servers globally still needing to update? Or should I worry that something has gone completely wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pingdom dns](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/) to help diagnose the problem

From the information you have provided it sounds like there isn't a problem and the incorrect nameservers are cached somewhere. Try clearing all your DNS caches. If this doesn't help it might be cached by your ISP.

Comment: pingdom dns gives 100% correct information... maybe our ISP is caching it.

Comment: Your records are cached all over the internet, it's not just your ISP.  Everyone who looked up the domain while you tried your new DNS provider cached records with the new info

Comment: @NicoHuysamen If pingdom is giving the correct information then it is fine. The other great thing about pingdom is you can use the advanced settings to test an undelegated nameserver, allowing you to change the nameserver to test a new configuration.

Answer (score 1):

try the dns checker from http://dns.squish.net/ - it's very helpful tool that should give you good insight. it will make a fresh dns requests every time.

Answer (score 0):

With so few details it's hard to say for sure, but this is more than likely an issue with cached `NS` records.  You may want to continue paying the 'new' provider until the TTL on your `NS` records expires; this way you can at least have service up while things settle down.